# SyntaxError: Unexpected token } curly brace in JSON

Tags: json, node.js, discord

Ok, for some reason, I tested something just to see if it would work and it gave me an error. I can't figure out what's wrong, it looks fine to me, I've compared and searched for an hour and nothing. I could be doing something really stupid but here.
This is bot.js

```
const botSettings = require("./botsettings.json");

console.log(botSettings.token);
console.log(botSettings.prefix);
```

This is package.json

```
{
  "name": "ultibot",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "a bot for the discord server The Ritual",
  "main": "bot.js",
  "author": "Rituliant",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^11.3.0"
  }
}
```

This is botsettings.json

```
{  
  "token": "thisisnormallyalongstringofrandomletters",
  "prefix": "!",
}
```

The full error is this

```
module.js:665
    throw err;
    ^

SyntaxError: C:\Users\quinb\DiscordBotJS\botsettings.json: Unexpected token } in JSON at position 98
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.Module._extensions..json (module.js:662:27)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\quinb\DiscordBotJS\bot.js:1:83)
    at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
```

Answer (score 2):

botsettings.json should be

```
{  
  "token": "thisisnormallyalongstringofrandomletters",
  "prefix": "!"
}
```

i.e. no comma after the prefix value.

Answer (score 1):

[JSON](http://json.org), unlike modern JavaScript, does not allow trailing commas in its object notation. So the final `}` in `botsettings.json` is indeed unexpected, because of the comma before it:

```
{  
  "token": "thisisnormallyalongstringofrandomletters",
  "prefix": "!",
               ^----- Here
}
```

That's only valid JSON if you remove that comma:

```
{  
  "token": "thisisnormallyalongstringofrandomletters",
  "prefix": "!"
}
```